# Christoffel symbols/ Christoffel forms

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, semi-riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a smooth manifold with connection $\nabla$. Then the definition for Christoffel symbols I am familiar with is

$\nabla_{\partial_i} \partial_j = \Gamma^h_{ij} \partial_h$

where $\{\partial_1,...,\partial_n\}$ is some smooth chart. Now I have seen an expression in a paper of the form

$\Gamma_f(h,k)$

where $h,k$ are tangent vectors and $f$ a point on the manifold (as far as I understood). What is the definition for this expression here? Also they call this the Christoffel forms, not symbols. Is there a difference? Are the definitions analogous?

Link to paper:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0312384.pdf

Comment: You should link the mentioned paper. Without context it is hard to tell. Edit: you should also tell us where exactly in the paper does this notation appear. It is a quite long paper and (after a small look) it seems that it does not appear in the first 20 pages